# Redirect Yii2 to a page when there is no connection

Tags: php, yii2

Yii2 shows

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable host.

when there is no internet access, how can I make it redirect to a page, says `./index.php?r=site/neterror`? I tried to do this in web/index.php by using this code

```
<?php
use yii\db\Exception;
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php');
try
{
    (new yii\web\Application($config))->run();  
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    header("Location: ./index.php?r=site/error"); /* Redirect browser */
    exit();
}
```

but all I get back is `The page isn't redirecting properly`.

Comment: just change your debug `YII_DEBUG` environment to 'false'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Database Exception View With different msg shown only when `YII_DEBUG` is `true` in Entry Script..

As Defined in Yii ErrorHandler Class to use Own View On UserException you have to false YII_DEBUG

```
class ErrorHandler extends \yii\base\ErrorHandler{
....
  protected function renderException($exception){
  ..
   $useErrorView = $response->format === Response::FORMAT_HTML && (!YII_DEBUG || $exception instanceof UserException);

    if ($useErrorView && $this->errorAction !== null) {
        $result = Yii::$app->runAction($this->errorAction);
        if ($result instanceof Response) {
            $response = $result;
        } else {
            $response->data = $result;
        }
    } 
  }


}
```